# What's the difference between noneism and Quine's ontology?

Tags: ontology

The [SEP entry on Richard (Routley) Sylvan](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sylvan-routley/#None) says

> From 1965 on, Sylvan argued that, through the influence of Quine, contemporary philosophy is committed to a fundamental mistake. Such a mistake, labelled the “Ontological Assumption” (cf. 1980), is represented by the view that one cannot make true statements about what does not exist. In opposition to this idea, Sylvan develops a theory about (non-existent) objects or, in Sylvan’s jargon, items--*noneism*.
>
> > [Noneism is] a very general theory of all items whatsoever, of those that are intensional and those that are not, of those that exist and those that do not (…); it is a theory of the logic and properties and kinds of properties of all items (1980, 5–6)
>
> Sylvan’s intuition is that, in order to be able to say something true about non-existent items, we need to allow for the possibility that non-existent items have properties. For instance, in order to be able to say that ‘Sherlock Holmes is a detective’ is true, Sherlock Holmes needs to have the property of *being a detective*.

This all seems very straightforward to me (with practically no understanding of ontology), but I take it this view is (was?) rather controversial. So how does Sylvan's view differ from (at the time) mainstream ontological views?

Comment: What Sylvan advocates is more commonly called [Meinongianism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonexistent-objects/#HisRooAleMeiProInt). Apart from that, philosophy, including some of Quine's own students, is no longer committed to Quine's criterion of ontological commitment, see e.g. Leng, [What's Wrong With Indispensability?](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225671806_What's_Wrong_With_Indispensability) One does not, however, need an ontology of nonexistent objects to drop it. A more common alternative is fictionalism, where "true" is replaced by "true according to a story".